# Started to play around with custom commands and would love help with understanding LaTeX hack codes

Tags: macros, learning

This may be a lot to answer at once, but I've come across some code in an old thread (pasted below) and don't really understand how it works.
I would greatly appreciate it someone could walkthorugh the code and explain it? 
(specifically how the `#` in `\def\Assign#1` works, the `\ifcsname` and `\global` operate)

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\Assign#1{% if \DP@#1 is defined append to it otherwise create it
  \ifcsname DP@#1\endcsname
    \edef\DP@tmp{\csname DP@#1\endcsname,\@currentlabel}%
  \else
    \edef\DP@tmp{\@currentlabel}%
  \fi
  \global\expandafter\let\csname DP@#1\endcsname\DP@tmp
  \typeout{ASSIGN: \csname DP@#1\endcsname}
}
\def\Assigned#1{%
  % \expandafter\def\csname Assigned#1\endcsname{\csname DP@#1\endcsname}
  \typeout{ASSIGNED: \csname DP@#1\endcsname}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Apples \Assign{fred}  
  \item Oranges \Assign{julie}
  \item Bananas \Assign{fred}
  \item Mangos \Assign{julie}
  \item Strawberries \Assign{julie}
\end{enumerate}

\Assigned{fred}   % should print 1,3  
\Assigned{julie}  % should print 2,4,5
\end{document}
```

Comment: It does print it out...in the log file.  (that is what `\typeout` does).  If you eliminate the word `\typeout` from the `\Assigned` definition, you will see it typeset in your document.

Comment: `\csname DP@#1\endcsname` are control sequences named, in your example, `\DP@fred` and `\DP@julie`. (of course you would need `\makeatletter` to access them in that form, without the `\csname`)

Comment: `#1`  is simply the first argument of the control sequence so in `\def\foo#1` mean that `\foo` must have one argument (e.g. `\foo{bah}`) and `\def\foo#1{\emph{#1}}` mean that `\foo`  will  type the argument with emphasis (e.g.  `\foo{bah}`will produce "*bah*").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\def\foo#1{...#1...}` is the primitive TeX way for defining one-argument macros.

In a LaTeX context, the code should have

```
\newcommand*{\Assign}[1]{...}

\newcommand*{\Assigned}[1]{...}
```

so as to check whether the macros are already defined and not be surprised of bizarre results.

The purpose of the code is to make an array of comma separated lists of numbers, each item is associated to a name and contains the list of tasks assigned to the person.

The task number is obtained with `\@currentlabel`, which expands to the representation of the last counter stepped with `\refstepcounter`; inside `enumerate`, `\@currentlabel` will expand to the current item number (with a prefix that, for first level `enumerate` environments, is empty).

The list of items is built incrementally and stored in a macro called `\DP@<name>`; for user `fred`, the macro is `\DP@fred`. However, using `\DP@#1` would not work in the code, because of how TeX reads input and splits it into tokens, so `\csname DP@#1\endcsname` has to be used to form the correct macro name.

The conditional `\ifcsname...\endcsname` returns true if the control sequence that would result from `\csname...\endcsname` has a definition, false otherwise. The code uses this in order to test if `\DP@<name>` exists or not: in the first case the next item number will be appended after a comma, otherwise just the number is appended.

For instance, the first `\Assign{fred}` will define `\DP@fred` to be `1`; the second one will append `,3`.

The code does this in an indirect way, using the scratch macro `\DP@tmp` (which is a bad choice, because if one of the user names is `tmp` chaos would ensue).

With `\edef\DP@tmp{...}` full expansion of the replacement text is performed before doing the macro definition, which does the expected work.

Next, `\DP@<name>` is assigned the same meaning as the scratch macro; this has to be done globally, because local macro definition would be forgotten at the end of the `enumerate` environment.

The primitive instruction for assigning a control sequence the same meaning as another token is `\let`; if prefixed with `\global`, the assignment is global. However in this case we need to use `\csname` to form the assignee, but

```
\global\let\csname DP@#1\endcsname\DP@tmp
```

would not work, because it would make `\csname` the same as `D`. The control sequence token has to be formed before `\let` enters action, so `\let` has to be preceded by `\expandafter`. By rule of TeX a `\global` prefix recursively expands the next token until finding something it can be legally prefixed to (`\let`, `\def` and some other primitive commands). Hence

```
\global\expandafter\let\csname DP@#1\endcsname\DP@tmp
```

Actually the intermediate step with the scratch macro is not really needed:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\Assign}[1]{% if \DP@#1 is defined append to it otherwise create it
  \ifcsname DP@#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\xdef\csname DP@#1\endcsname{\csname DP@#1\endcsname,\@currentlabel}%
  \else
    \expandafter\xdef\csname DP@#1\endcsname{\@currentlabel}%
  \fi
  \typeout{ASSIGN: \csname DP@#1\endcsname}
}
\newcommand*{\Assigned}[1]{%
  % \expandafter\def\csname Assigned#1\endcsname{\csname DP@#1\endcsname}
  \typeout{ASSIGNED: \csname DP@#1\endcsname}
}
\makeatother
```

would do as well and avoid the possible issue with a user named `tmp`.

The commented line in the definition of `\Assigned` would make a “user level” macro `\Assigned<name>`. If you uncomment it, the call `\Assigned{fred}` will print the list of tasks in the log file and the console, after making `\Assignedfred` equivalent to `\DP@fred`.

A better way to accomplish the same would be

```
\global\expandafter\let\csname Assigned#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname DP@#1\endcsname
```

I added `\global` for the same reason as before.